# Accessing data from mongoDB on EJS page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I need some on-hmtl-page javascript to be able to access data from my mongoDB database. I use mongoose to find all the documents from the collection I'm interested in, store them in an array and render it on an ejs page. But I get an error ("invalid or unexpected token), and I think that it's because the _id field is not stored as a string (it has no ""/''). I've tried client-side and server side to convert the Id field to a string but to no avail. Any idea why it isn't a string or how to convert it?

app.js

```
app.get('/stats', function(req,res){
    pomodoroModel.find({}, function(err, studyHistory){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            // send study history
            res.render('graph', {studyHistory: studyHistory});
        }
    });
});
```

this is what studyHistory looks like console.logged in app.js

```
[ { _id: 5cdf0e14a4dfa719beef5cfa,
    subject: 'Math',
    timeInterval: 36142,
    __v: 0 },
{ _id: 5cdf0f5404467519d5136748,
    subject: 'History',
    timeInterval: 43322,
    __v: 0 } ]
```

EJS page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
let studyHistoryData = <%- studyHistory %>;
```

The code in the browser where the error occurs

```
let studyHistoryData = { _id: 5cdf0e14a4dfa719beef5cfa,
subject: 'Math',
timeInterval: 36142,
__v: 0 },{ _id: 5cdf0f5404467519d5136748,
subject: 'History',
timeInterval: 43322,
__v: 0 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to render `studyHistory` as JSON string

```
res.render('graph', {studyHistory: JSON.stringify(studyHistory)});
```

and then parse it in your ejs file like this:

```
let studyHistoryData = JSON.parse('<%- studyHistory %>');
```